# reading a list into a function

Tags: python, list

new here, quite noob but learning something every day. any help would be much appreciated

so i have 2 files and i am trying to read a list from another file in this way:

from 2ndpage import *

main.py

```
listx = [ ["BMW", "True", "99"], 
          ["Honda", "False", "06"],
          ["Toyota", "True", "88 ]  ]

x = input("What car are you looking for? : ")
findthis(x)
```

2ndpage.py

```
from main import listx
def findthis(car):
    for row in listx:
        i=0
        if car in listx[i]:
            print(car)     # printing all the list that contains the car name
        else:
            i=+1
```

### AttributeError: partially initialized module '2ndpage' has no attribute 'findthis' (most likely due to ## a circular import)

not sure how to make it work. the list has to be on the main page and to call the function on the main page as well. and the function def has to be on the second page.
any help would be much appreciated. thank you

Comment: Just like it says, you have circular import: modules import each other. Arrange the code so that the dependency is one-directional, for example, pass `listx` to `findthis` as an argument or move it to the second module.

Comment: Never reimport the module you are starting (here: `main.py`)! It will lead to a circular import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is classic Circular dependency import. If to say simply: you try to import main file to 2ndpage and 2ndpage to main and they are keep importing themself in loop.

So you need to move your list to one file like:

```
listx = [ ["BMW", "True", "99"], 
          ["Honda", "False", "06"],
          ["Toyota", "True", "88" ]
        ]

def findthis(car):
    for row in listx:
        i=0
        if car in listx[i]:
            print(car)     # printing all the list that contains the car name
        else:
            i=+1
```

And in *main.py* you just do

```
findthis(x)
```

Comment: thing is, i cant move the list to another page, thats what confuses me :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add another paramether to findthis function.
`findthis(car,list)`
This should work. Now you dont need to import your listx.

Comment: not allowed to add more paramethers either saddly

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, your code causes a circular import. One thing you could do is to make your `findthis` take a list and a name as an argument and then import it from *2ndpage.py* into *main.py* and call it with `listx` and `x` as arguments.

Your *2ndpage.py* would then look something like this:

```
def findthis(car_list, car_name):
    for row in car_list:
        i=0
        if car_name in car_list[i]:
            print(car_name)
        else:
            i=+1
```

and your *main.py* something like this:

```
from 2ndpage import findthis

listx = [ ["BMW", "True", "99"], 
          ["Honda", "False", "06"],
          ["Toyota", "True", "88" ] ]

x = input("What car are you looking for? : ")
findthis(listx, x)
```